# angularjs $http(config) ith data from form not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-promise

I have an issue with $http in angularjs :

```
app.controller('ctrlProfil', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.loginProfil = "<?= $_SESSION['login']?>";
  $scope.mdpProfil = "<?= $_SESSION['mdp']?>";
  $scope.emailProfil = "<?= $_SESSION['email']?>";

  var config = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'modifProfil.php',
    data: $('#formProfil').serialize()
  }
  $scope.submit = function(){
  $http(config).
  then(function(response){

    console.log(response);
    console.log($('#formProfil').serialize());


  })
    }
});
```

my form =>

```
<form id="formProfil" ng-submit="submit()">
        <p><span>Bonjour  </span><input  type="text" name="loginProfil" value="{{loginProfil}}"/></p>
        <p>Mon mot de passe:  <input  type="text" name="mdpProfil" value="{{mdpProfil}}"/></p>
        <p> Email:  <input  type="email" name="emailProfil" value="{{emailProfil}}"/></p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Enregistrer"/>
      </form>
```

my php code =>

```
try
{
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=monprojet;charset=UTF8', 'root', 'root');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
$login = $_POST['loginProfil'];
$mdp = $_POST['mdpProfil'];
$email = $_POST['emailProfil'];

$rep = $db->query('SELECT id FROM utilisateur WHERE login='.$_SESSION['login']);
$reponse = $db->prepare('UPDATE utilisateur SET login= :login, mdp= :mdp, email= :email WHERE id='.$rep);
$reponse->execute(array(
  ':login' => $login,
  ':mdp' => $mdp,
  ':email' => $email
));
$json = json_encode($reponse->fetchAll());
$reponse->closeCursor();
echo $json;
```

i can't manage to send the data via the $http(config), i have an error telling me :

> Notice:  Undefined index: loginProfil in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/izad/git/modifProfil.php on line 15
>
> Notice:  Undefined index: mdpProfil in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/izad/git/modifProfil.php on line 17
>
> Notice:  Undefined index: emailProfil in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/izad/git/modifProfil.php on line 19

but my index are defined, need some help to understand this one

Thanks

Comment: Use php code in Angular front end app is a BIG mistake... i think you don't really understand difference between Client / Server side language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add headers **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** to receive the data in **GET/POST** request in php.

> By default, the $http service will transform the outgoing request by
>   serializing the data as JSON

Change your **$http request** to this:

```
var config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'modifProfil.php',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: $('#formProfil').serialize()
          }
          $scope.submit = function(){
          $http(config).
          then(function(response){

            console.log(response);
            console.log($('#formProfil').serialize());

      })
```

You can also add headers for all **$http request** like this:

```
myapp.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function () {
  return {
    request: function (config) {

      config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

      return config;
    }
  };
});

myapp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```